# PHP error_log() isn't working

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

I'm working on a basic app that doesn't use any framework, and no `debug = 1`. I'm trying to figure out how to show php's `var_dump`s and `error_log`s, but I'm not sure where they are supposed to be printed.

I'm using PHP's built-in server at localhost.
Here is my html:

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <pre>

    </pre>  

</body>
</html>
```

I thought `session_start()` would have the php `var_dump`s show before the html, but there isn't anything.

I also tried installing ChromePHP, I could get it to print things in the HTML, but not when I moved the statements into the PHP code.

I also have this class logging some errors:

```
class Utils {

    public static function log($message)
    {
        @error_log($message, 0);
    }

}
```

I tried changing it to `error_log($message, 3, './mylog.txt')`; still nothing.

This is probably the most basic question ever written, but I have no idea how to debug plain PHP.

Comment: I would remove the @ in front of the error_log. PHP will write to stderr by default on the command line. If the file is not writable it will also fallback to stderr. Make sure the file is writable "chmod +w ./mylog.txt"

Comment: var_dump has absolutely nothing to do with sessions or error reporting/logging. It's no different to using echo

Comment: laura: that means code wasn't executed, which is why there isn't a line number. It looks like your issue isn't the logging, but might be where you're running "php -S"? Is there an index.php in the directory you're running php -S?

Comment: I did all of the above and it's still not logging anything...I think what I'm asking is how do I `var_dump` anything in plain PHP, more specifically where is it supposed to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Beside session_start() there is no PHP-Command in your code. No echo, no var_dump... and session_start is written correctly. What PHP does in that case is starting the session and return the rest of your Html-Code to the browser.

So there is no real problem here.

If you want to see something,

```
// you should try
echo "Test, PHP is working";
```

If you don't see anything here, then your Webserver doesn't work properly. Look into which port you should use and see whether the service is running.

In case you have further code which you want to debug, there are some commands to define the output.

```
// Look up those:
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Does this help?